# JSON Creating Approach

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I am working on an IOS project. I am trying to create Twitter. I am using Firebase Database. As you know Firebase uses JSON and i am confused about database creation.

First of all i have users with name, surname, email,username and profilepic URL.

Also i have posts which has a string named as post but as you know i need to show users in my post. A post object has its user's name, profilepic and username

And also users can follow another users and their timeline should have only posts sent by the users they follow.

This structure confuses me a lot here is a solution i have found and example of my json files

```
{
"users" : {
"1SUbzM6rIRTQexrOgJ8BnDBCDWt2" : {
  "email" : "Test1@test.com",
  "fullname" : "Test1 Test1",
  "name" : "Test1",
  "surname" : "Test1",
  "username" : "@test1",
  "ppurl" : "www.ppurl.com/ppppp",
  "posts" : {}
},
"4vBvO9vURkPneusviRGxKglJ3n32" : {
    "email" : "Test2@test.com",
    "fullname" : "Test2 Test2",
    "name" : "Test2",
    "surname" : "Test2",
    "username" : "@test2",
    "ppurl" : "www.ppurl.com/ppppp",
    "posts" : {
            "34E20A52-8E66-4AF7-8DA4-73BDE9185FCB" : {
                "post" : "Bir post daha\n"
            },

            "59798B81-4510-4E63-8050-3AF04698C7B0" : {
                "post" : "3. Postumuz gör better approach"
                }
            },
    "follows" : {
        "5QaOU5Pd05h2M8wExcUteUg6mlJ2" : {
            "email" : "TEST3@TEST.com",
            "fullname" : "TEST3 TEST3",
            "name" : "TEST3",
            "surname" : "TEST3"
            "username" : "@test3",
            "ppurl" : "www.ppurl.com/ppppp",
            "posts" : {}
            },
        "6y0RLGGCw6Zg5RHgPxghKUId9pJ3" : {
            "email" : "TEST4@jjj.hhh",
            "fullname" : "TEST4 TEST4",
            "name" : "TEST4",
            "surname" : "TEST4",
            "username" : "@test4",
            "ppurl" : "www.ppurl.com/ppppp",
            "posts" : {}
            },

    },
},      
"5QaOU5Pd05h2M8wExcUteUg6mlJ2" : {
  "email" : "TEST3@TEST.com",
  "fullname" : "TEST3 TEST3",
  "name" : "TEST3",
  "surname" : "TEST3"
  "username" : "@test3",
  "ppurl" : "www.ppurl.com/ppppp",
  "posts" : {}
},
"6y0RLGGCw6Zg5RHgPxghKUId9pJ3" : {
  "email" : "TEST4@jjj.hhh",
  "fullname" : "TEST4 TEST4",
  "name" : "TEST4",
  "surname" : "TEST4"
  "username" : "@test4",
  "ppurl" : "www.ppurl.com/ppppp",
  "posts" : {}
  }

}
```

Is this a right approach? Users and posts duplicates and it is too hard to reach a data from the swift. Should i save posts different from users but if i do with this approach i cannot get post's username , name and ppurl etc.

How should i construct my JSON file and create relationships using the most efficient way.

Edit:

I can get my json files to my project. My question is : Is it true to write the same user 2-3 times ? I have a user already in my json file but when someone follows someone should i write it again inside of the friends attribute ? Or can i get reference with only id.

Comment: Basically it's no problem to parse that JSON into a model in Swift but I would declare `users`, `posts` and `follows` as arrays, not dictionaries, putting the identifier key (like `34E20A52-8E66-4AF7-8DA4-73BDE9185FCB`) **into** the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simpler structure like this one:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "identifier": "1SUbzM6rIRTQexrOgJ8BnDBCDWt2",
            "email": "Test1@test.com",
            "fullname": "Test1 Test1",
            "name": "Test1",
            "surname": "Test1",
            "username": "@test1",
            "ppurl": "www.ppurl.com/ppppp"
        },
        {
            "identifier": "4vBvO9vURkPneusviRGxKglJ3n32",
            "email": "Test2@test.com",
            "fullname": "Test2 Test2",
            "name": "Test2",
            "surname": "Test2",
            "username": "@test2",
            "ppurl": "www.ppurl.com/ppppp",
            "posts": [
                "34E20A52-8E66-4AF7-8DA4-73BDE9185FCB",
                "59798B81-4510-4E63-8050-3AF04698C7B0"
            ],
            "follows": [
                "5QaOU5Pd05h2M8wExcUteUg6mlJ2",
                "6y0RLGGCw6Zg5RHgPxghKUId9pJ3"
            ]
        },
        {
            "identifier": "5QaOU5Pd05h2M8wExcUteUg6mlJ2",
            "email": "TEST3@TEST.com",
            "fullname": "TEST3 TEST3",
            "name": "TEST3",
            "surname": "TEST3",
            "username": "@test3",
            "ppurl": "www.ppurl.com/ppppp"
        },
        {
            "identifier": "6y0RLGGCw6Zg5RHgPxghKUId9pJ3",
            "email": "TEST4@jjj.hhh",
            "fullname": "TEST4 TEST4",
            "name": "TEST4",
            "surname": "TEST4",
            "username": "@test4",
            "ppurl": "www.ppurl.com/ppppp"
        }
    ]
}
```

Otherwise you're JSON payload is going to grow bigger and bigger over time.

**EDIT** Just saw @vadian comment... Let's say it's based on his idea then.

Comment: Thank you for the reply ! But where i store post text ?

Comment: You can store it in another array at the same level as `users`, named `posts`.